# Having trouble displaying a button once when is clicked

Tags: c#, button, webforms, buttonclick

have a c# webform that has two buttons that can edit the fields of the form. An edit button once clicked needs to enable all the fields of the document to be updated and display a save button.  I have the save button not visible but cant figure out how to make it visible once the saved button is clicked also how do I disable all the field so their not edittable until the edit button is clicked.

this is what I have tried for the button click visibile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function script1() {
    Button2.onclientclick = (Button3.Visible = true);
  }
  </script>

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="24px" 
        Text="Edit" Width="67px" onclientclick="script1()"/>
```

also:

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Button3.Visible = true;
  }
```

Comment: The JavaScript block is written like it's C#, which is why it doesn't work (there is no onclientclick property of HTML button; there is no Visible property either). The C# block should work, but the Button in the markup needs to have an OnClick attribute that ponts to that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="24px" 
    Text="Edit" Width="67px" onclientclick="script1()" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
```

Add to your button delegate in side server

```
OnClick="Button2_Click"
```

Comment: What I don't get is that yes that works but if I take the javascipt script1() out but leave the "onclientclick="script1()" in it stills works but i have nothing determining what script1() is cause I took it out.

Comment: It's normal he executes client script and finish with server script

Comment: try without client script and test

Comment: On this webform I have checkboxes and textboxes is their a way that these can be seen just not editted until the button is clicked as well I want them to be visible but not edittable until that same button is clicked as well.

Comment: yes i took the javascript function out but left the onclientclick= and added the onclick and it still works but i feel like the onclicentclick isn't pointing to anything cause I took that method out.

Comment: try with the property Enabled,PLease LewSim add new question, and i bring answer

Comment: The C# method `Button2_Click` is doing the work. JavaScript is not doing anything. That's why it doesn't matter if `script1` is defined.

Comment: yes i get that but if I take the onclientclick=script1 out it doesnt work but their is no method defining script1 anywhere